# The correct way of initialize dropdown in initState Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an own DropDown widget that have an List items and selectedValue property that are final.

Since they are final, I should create myDropdown in the parent Page's initState method in one step.  The selectedValue and the elements of dropdown are stored in different tables so I could use two

```
getTableElements().then((onValue) {
});
```

inside each other and initialze MyDropdownButton inside the second. Because initstate cannot be async.
Is there a better solution for this so when **Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {** get its control the myDropDown widget be fully initialize?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in initState method you can call it

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((callback) async {
    /// getTableElements().then((onValue) {
}); 
})
```

Comment: "Schedule a callback for the end of this frame."   I need the opposite. The build should wait until the async methods to be finished and create my own widget to pass to the build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<int>(
    future: future.whichReturnsDataForDropdonwn(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasError) {
        return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
      }
      if(!snapshot.hasData) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      return DropdownButton<int>(
        // use snapshot.data
      );
    }
  );
}
```